# python random choice without duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Hi everyone I would like to avoid the duplicate questions in my chatbot and chatbot just ask three questions which is in the list and after that just return thank for your help

```
@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
    symptom = request.args.get('msg')
    questions = ['What is altin cuzdan?', 'how we can sell the gold?', 'how we can buy the gold?','who are you?', 'how we can change our password?']
    #time.sleep(5)
    #sampling = random.choice(questions, )
    questions2 = questions[:]
    questions2.remove(quesuions)
    return random.choice(questions2)
```

Comment: What is the user input you would like to skip?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: You cannot change `questions` *inside* a function. You must store what already has been asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabye something in this manner with an "asked questions" list as an argument? Either way as commented by @usr2564301 you will have to store which questions are asked outside of function.

```
@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response(norepeat):
    symptom = request.args.get('msg')
    questions = ['What is altin cuzdan?', 'how we can sell the gold?', 'how we can buy the gold?','who are you?', 'how we can change our password?']
    #time.sleep(5)
    #sampling = random.choice(questions, )
    questions2 = questions[:]
    questions2.remove(questions)
    while True:
        return_question = random.choice(questions2)
        if return_question in norepeat:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return random.choice(questions2)



norepeat = []
while True:
    question = get_bot_response(norepeat)
    norepeat.append(question)
```